# Uable to connect Splunk using php sdk

Tags: php, splunk

I am trying to connect Splunk using PHP SDK but I am getting following errors:

```
https://api.9xnn-6gtz.data.splunkstorm.com:80/services/auth/login Warning: array_shift() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/u354848659/public_html/oauth/splunk/Splunk/Http.php on line 124 

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/u354848659/public_html/oauth/splunk/Splunk/Http.php on line 126

Login Failed. Reason: String could not be parsed as XML
```

```
$SplunkExamples_connectArguments = array(
    'host' => 'example.com',
    'port' => '80',
    'username' => 'xxxx',
    'password' => 'xxxx',
    'token' => 'xxxxxxxxxxx',
);
```

I passed all above details. But when I am trying to run it is not working. Kindly help me out in resolving the issue at the earliest. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to give more code of what you're doing with this. One of your warning messages states you're passing a null, Here you're showing us an array, which gives me some ideas of what might be wrong, but you're not showing us how you use this array. You should try putting together a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/).

From the [getting started guide](http://dev.splunk.com/view/php-sdk/SP-CAAAEP4), the example does not pass a token. The reason for this, if you dig into [the documentation](http://docs.splunk.com/DocumentationStatic/PHPSDK/1.0/classes/Splunk_Service.html#method___construct) you'll see that if you provide a token, then the username and password is ignored and you don't need to call login().

Furthermore, using the PHP SDK (and other SDKs), you need to hit the Splunk REST API port, which by default is port 8089, not port 80. This is configurable of course, so you should double check with your Splunk Administrator.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Please see below URL to see Http.php code. I updated port to 8089. Also I removed token from code. http://empower-demos.twomini.com/oauth/splunk/Splunk/Http.html  You can also check my example on link : http://empower-demos.twomini.com/oauth/splunk/examples/

Comment: Did it help you solve your issue or not? Splunk/Http.php is part of the Splunk SDK. It's unlikely that your issue is actually there (It's possible could be, but you haven't shown enough of what you have written and what you have tried / expected for us to believe that). Update your question with an SSCCE of how you're using the SDK if the notes I have here I've put here did not solve your issue (Don't link to external sites for your question's content, especially ones that are not running a reachable webserver.)

Comment: Issue is not solve yet. I am not able to connect to Splunk server using php SDK yet. I just passed given credentials to url given in example by replacing my host : $url = 'https://myhost.com:8089/services/auth/login'; Also try to detect it using simple CURL. but no success... :(

Comment: Looking at your other questions, and then noticing the URL here again, Splunk Storm is a different product from Splunk Enterprise, and does not yet support those APIs. (Also port 443 for their Data Input API)